# Properly compiling modules in subfolders (ocamlbuild)

Tags: compilation, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I recently decided to organize the files in my project directory. I moved the parsers I had for a few different file types into their own directory and also decided to use ocamlbuild (the as the project was getting more complicated and the simple shell script was not sufficient any longer).

I was able to successfully include external projects by modifying myocamlbuild with some basic rules (calling `ocaml_lib`, I'll use ocamlfind some other time), but I am stuck on how to include the folder as a module into the project properly. I created a `parser.mlpack` file and filled it with the proper modules to be included (eg, "parser/Date", et cetera), wrote a `parser.mli` in the root of the directory for their implementations, and modified the `_tags` file (see below).

During the compilation, the parser directory is traversed properly, and `parser.cmi`, `parser.mli.depends` were both created in the `_build` directory; as well as all `*.cm[xio]` files in the parsers subdirectory.

I feel I might be doing something redundant, but regardless, the project *still* cannot find the Parser module when I compile!

Thanks!

**_tags**

```
debug : true
<*.ml> : annot
"parser" : include
<parser/*.cmx>: for-pack(Parser)
<curlIO.*> : use_curl
<mySQL.*> : use_mysql
<**/*.native> or <**/*.byte> : use_str,use_unix,use_curl,use_mysql
```

**compilation error**

```
/usr/local/bin/ocamlopt.opt unix.cmxa str.cmxa -g -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/site-lib/mysql mysql.cmxa -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/curl curl.cmxa curlIO.cmx utilities.cmx date.cmx fraction.cmx logger.cmx mySQL.cmx data.cmx project.cmx -o project.native  
File "\_none\_", line 1, characters 0-1:  
Error: **No implementations provided for the following modules:**
         Parser referenced from project.cmx  
Command exited with code 2.
```

You'll notice `-I parser` is not included in the linking phase above; actually none of the parser related files are included!

*edit:* Added new details from comments and answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if `parser.mli` is somehow interfering with the dependencies in processing the mlpack file.  `parser.cmi` will be generated from the pack operation when `parser.mlpack` is processed and compiled.  Try building with the `parser.mli` file removed.  If that works, then this can be re-processed into a real answer.

Also, you don't need `parser/` as a prefix to your modules in `parser.mlpack` if `parser.mlpack` is in the `parser` directory and you have the `include` tag set.  But that shouldn't make a difference for this.

**Update**: this worked around the problem, but wasn't the root cause.  Root cause, per comment below, was a file mentioned in the `.mlpack` that had been relocated.

Comment: Yes, this worked, But does not have the intended consequences. A module representing the contents of the directory was not created; they are referenced by the submodules directly. The `-pack` argument is added to the proper modules during compilation though. But not used in the final product. Is my interpretation about -pack incorrect?

Comment: `-pack` should create a module which contains the other modules as submodules.  Your other code must then refer to them as their submodules (e.g. `Parser.ConfParser`); if it ever refers to them directly (just `ConfParser` without first `open`ing `Parser`), then things will get messed up.

Could you post the `-verbose` output when you don't have `parser.mli`?

Comment: I added back the parser.mli file. I think for some reason an error while compiling the pack didn't break where it should. **There was an extra module in my `mlpack` file that I had moved**.

Answer (score 4):

You need to "include" the parser directory in the search path.  You can do this in `_tags`:

```
"parser": include
```

Then `ocamlbuild` can search the parser directory for interesting files.

Comment: ... I modified my question above. This helped, but I was actually already doing this, but from the equivalence on the command line with `-I parser`. Now, I just build with `ocamlbuild project.<target>`

Comment: Let's try something else then :).  Done as a separate answer since it's really another approach.

Comment: (just to be complete, you may know this already)  

<parser> or "parser" will work, but "parser" is correct since I'm not trying to do any pattern matching.