# ocamlbuild; building toplevel

Tags: build-automation, ocaml, compilation, ocamlbuild

Having successfully [reorganized my project for ocamlbuild with subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209532/properly-compiling-modules-in-subfolders-ocamlbuild) and using ocamlfind, I've found it difficult to build the top-level.

I've constructed a `.mltop` file containing all the modules that would be included and added the packages to the `_tags`, but the build doesn't work. It cannot find the C functions that are compiled with one of the modules. With `-classic-display` on, I can see that file, `libcside.a`, not being included and isn't even being compiled at all! The c file is added as a dependency in `myocamlbuild.ml` by,

```
flag ["link"; "ocaml"; "use_cutil"] (S [A"-cclib"; A"-L."; ]);
dep  ["link"; "ocaml"; "use_cutil"] ["libcside.a"];
```

and in `_tags`,

```
<utilities.*> : use_cutil
<**/*.top> : use_str, use_unix, use_cutil, use_curl, use_mysql
```

and, finally, in `libcside.clib`,

```
cutil.o
```

I'm missing something in setting up the build for the top level, but I cannot find a reliable resource online. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I presume that cutil.ml describes ocaml side of libcside.a - correct?
- Did you put Cutil in mltop?
- With your current plugin cutil ocaml library will not link libcside.a in (`dep` only instructs ocamlbuild to build it, not link)
- Here is a simple (and working) way to build project-local ocaml library with C stubs. In myocamlbuild.ml:

  ```
  ocaml_lib "linuxnet";
  let liblinuxnet_stubs = "liblinuxnet_stubs." ^ !Options.ext_lib in
  flag ["link"; "ocaml"; "use_linuxnet"] (S[A"-cclib"; A liblinuxnet_stubs;]);
  dep  ["link"; "ocaml"; "use_linuxnet"] [liblinuxnet_stubs];
  ```

  In liblinuxnet_stubs.clib:

  ```
  linuxnet_c.o
  ```

  Notice that the C source is called `linuxnet_c.c` so that the resulting object file doesn't override the one from linuxnet.ml (or vice versa). And finally in _tags:

  ```
  true: use_linuxnet
  ```

  With this setup it will be available in toplevel (note that there is no need to put `Linuxnet` into .mltop cause linuxnet.cma will be added to link by `use_linuxnet` flag (generated with `ocaml_lib` usage)).

Comment: 1. Utilities does
2. yes.
3. yes, this did it. thanks. I was had added the A"libcside" to the flags, but it hadn't worked. I was missing ocaml_lib. thanks!