# How to make OCamlbuild compile and link a C file into an OCaml project?

Tags: c, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'm trying to build an OCaml binary `main.native` from `main.ml` that also relies on a single C file `custom.c` to implement a new primitive. This C file needs to be compiled and linked. Is there a way to do this just with a `_tags` file? The obvious problem is that OCamlbuild does not detect the dependency when scanning `main.ml` and hence needs to be told explicitly about the dependency.

```
ocamlbuild main.native
```

OCamlbuild knows a rule to compile a *.c file to a *.o file but I don't know how to add the dependency.

Comment: Oasis can generate suitable `myocamlbuild.m` and `_tags` files. Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I haven't tried to use Oasis. The main reason is that I would prefer not to rely on tools outside the OCaml distribution if possible. If necessary, I would implement a `myocamlbuild.ml` that adds the required dependency.

Comment: Oasis generates `myocamlbuild.ml` and other files. The result seems to be compilable without oasis installed .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a [number](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.caml/Ac6AyNIEOsA) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374136/ocamlbuild-building-toplevel) [resources](http://l-lang.blogspot.com/2012/08/incorporating-c-code-in-ocaml-project.html) [out](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Ocamlbuild_example_with_C_stubs) [there](http://mancoosi.org/~abate/ocamlbuild-stubs-and-dynamic-libraries).

The first thing is that you need to tag the `main.native` as to create a dependency on the c-stubs and link accordingly. (By the way, this assumes the c-library is called `cstub`, but it can be anything you'd like).

`_tags` :

```
<*.{byte,native}> : use_cstub
<**/*.cm{x,}a>    : use_cstub
```

Then, in `myocamlbuild.ml` create a dependency of a c-library to the things tagged,

```
dep ["link";"ocaml";"use_cstub"] ["libcstub.a"]
```

[OCamlbuild has rules for creating library files](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/d9a035fa65dcbf4ab11207556dedb5785c16659b/ocamlbuild/ocaml_specific.ml#L270-L278) (*.so and *.a), but you would need to add a listing of the files to be built against in a `.clib` file,

`cstub.clib` :

```
cobjfile1.o
cobjfile2.o
...
```

Any header files also need to be copied over from the main directory to the `_build/` directory. This is done by specifying they are a dependency on compilation in c (in `myocamlbuild.ml`, where `headers` is a list of strings naming the header files in the project.

```
dep ["c"; "compile"] headers;
```

and finally, adding flags to when we link the project with the c-stub library (also in `myocamlbuild.ml`),

```
flag ["link";"ocaml";"use_cstub"] (S[A"-dllib";A"-lcstub";A"-cclib";A"-lcstub"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for going into the details. I guess this also means: `myocamlbuild.ml` is required and the problem can't be solved with `_tags` alone.

Comment: The [second resource](http://l-lang.blogspot.de/2012/08/incorporating-c-code-in-ocaml-project.html) was very helpful. It provides a minimal plugin that implements a parametrized flag `linkdep()` that can be used to include link dependencies into a `_tags` file.

Answer (score 2):

I have accepted the answer above but would like to document the solution. As mentioned in a comment, I have created a new parametrized tag `linkdep()` using `myocamlbuild.ml`:

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin;;

dispatch 
    ( function 
    | After_rules -> pdep ["link"] "linkdep" (fun param -> [param])
    | _           -> ()
    )
```

The newly created tag is used in `_tags` to add a link dependency:

```
<*.ml>:     annot
<*.byte>:   linkdep(custom_unix_stubs.o),custom
<*.native>: linkdep(custom_unix_stubs.o)
```

This relies on built-in rules to compile a C file to an object file. However, this would still miss dependencies on header files (which I don't have).